# Redux-toolkit и получение значений из стора после запросов

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, асинхронность, promise

Идея была в том, что с помощью rtk-query загружать картинки. Сначала пробовал через Promise.all().then(), в then() я должен был получить заполненный массив. Но и этого не получил. Теперь попробовал так:

```
const buildingsMediaData = useSelector((state) => state.buildingsState.buildingsMediaData); 
...
const [uploadMedia, { isLoading, isSuccess, error, isError }] = useUploadMediaMutation();
...
 const handleOnSubmit = async (evt) => {

 try {
  let promises = imgFiles.map((imgFile) =>
    uploadMedia({
      file: imgFile,
      type: 'BUILDING_IMG_TYPE',
    }).unwrap()
  );

  let results = await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log(results, buildingsMediaData); // Почему buildingsMediaData пустой?
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}};
```

В слайсе пробовал через extraReducers заполнять

```
const initialState = {
  buildingsMediaData: [],
};

export const buildingsSlice = createSlice({
  initialState,
  name: 'buildingsSlice',
  reducers: {
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(buildingsApi.endpoints.uploadMedia.matchFulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.buildingsMediaData = [ 
        ...current(state).buildingsMediaData,
        {
          respValue: action.payload, 
          uploaded: true
        }];// В массиве, для примера, эти значения
    });
  },
});
```

После выполнения запросов buildingsMediaData остаётся пустым, хотя в Redux Dev Tools он заполнен

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что состояние не успело обновиться. добавьте в компонент useEffect на вашу buildingsMediaData и посмотрите, когда приходит обновление

Comment: @SwaD Да, но мне кажется это такое себе. Я думал, что в каком-нибудь then() это всё будет работать. Или забить на всё и написать createAsyncThunk. Даже незнаю

Comment: Ну пришли из хранилища данные чуть позже... Что с того?